# How to include Android activities and screens in a UML class diagram?

Tags: android, android-activity, uml, class-diagram

I need to make a class diagram in order to document an application I have been developing. The original one, which was used for me to plan the implementation is as follows:

[image: current class diaram]

Unfortunately this is incomplete since I have no idea how to show the Activities that compose my application. The activities would be where the presentation package is. I looked through some similar questions on this site, it seems like some suggested to make a separate diagram just for the Activities, would this really be the case? If not, how would I include them all into one class diagram?

Comment: Activities are just classes, right? They have their own dependencies, such as the views and the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UML has 14 diagrams to show different aspect of your app. You should use different diagrams to show different aspects, basicaly broken into **structural** and **behavioral** aspects.

Classes show the structure of your system, while activities show its behavioral features. Activities are used to show wide range of behavior, going from overall usage scenarios, down to single method algorithms. Of course, you don't need to document each single aspect in UML, that would probably be waste of effort, so you should wisely chose some meaningfull things to show.

It's always better to have several simple diagrams than a single large one. Even this class diagram you posted as an example is too lagre and complex to be useful. I recommend you to break in into several simper ones, even to structure the classes into packages and provide a bird-view package diagram with dependencies.

Comment: Since this is the case, I guess I will be making a separate behavioral class diagram with just the activities and keep this one as the structural one.  
Also, it wouldn't be that large if it weren't for the implementations of interfaces. Would it be a good practice to perhaps just show the interfaces in the class diagram, and then make separate diagrams of the implementation and extension classes?

Comment: Sounds good. There are no written rules on making good models, rather put yourself in the shoes of someone who does not know anything about your system and must read your model. What would be useful for him to see first? Make him easy way of getting to know your model gradually. Show first your architectonic relevant things (interfaces, major dependencies) and then separatelly the details of each module/package. Activity diagram can act like glue here, connecting different parts and showing how they are supposed to be used or implemented.